# SVG drawing application with vector export

Tags: javascript, pdf, vector, svg, raphael

I want to create a drawing application where I can place text and images on a canvas. Those elements also need to be interactively manipulated. Eventually the resulting canvas has to be exported to a vector based PDF. An excellent contender for this functionality would be SVG.

However, this application also needs to be crossbrowser compatible. I've been browsing around for some time now and have seen a couple of solutions available. I found among others [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) and Google's [SVGWeb](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/) for working with SVG.

Now for converting those SVG files to a PDF I'm not sure if for instance [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) will offer me what I am looking for.

Also, how would bitmap images be handled when converting the SVG to PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images within a PDF have to be part of the PDF.  They can use any number of compression techniques (jpeg, fax, jbig2, zip, gif, a couple others), various bits per color, various colors per pixel, and so forth... but the pixels must be defined within that PDF.

I've used Batik myself.  A little clunky in combination with iText (surprisingly large amount of code involved), but quite serviceable.  The only thing that really bugged me was that it wouldn't draw text as text... Batik insists on drawing it as paths.  They may have overcome this since I started using it a year or two ago.  But that was kind of a deal breaker (HUGE pdf bloat) so we ended up rendering our text separately: PITA, potential z-order issues (that never came up for us), plus a couple subtle interal layout issues that didn't turn up till later.

Batik supports script, animation, and a variety of Other Things that don't really matter within the bounds of SVG->PDF conversion.  There's at least one other Java SVG library out there that is much more compact(not as feature rich... half empty/half full), though I can't for the life of me remember the name at the moment.  The name came up on the iText mailing list maybe a year ago?  Don't recall exactly.  Quite some time ago, and AFTER I got Batik working.  Ah well.

Answer (score 0):

Batik can convert svg to pdf, Inkscape or Adobe Illustrator can too AFAIK.

Comment: internal PDF conversion?  I was under the impression (from a couple years ago) that it requires iText's PdfGraphics2D class.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Inkscape would be your best choice here, it mostly sticks to SVG 1.1 for the shapes it implements (using a few of its own properties, which you can get rid of if you save it as a plain SVG). For me, even when I save as an Inkscape SVG, it displays fine in browsers even with blurs, though it won't work in Internet Explorer. For that, there is no solution besides using an external tool such as (as you've already found) SVGWeb. Unfortunately, javascript support for SVG can differ between browsers, and there is no way to fix this.

As for PDF, I think that raster images are embedded if they are embedded within the SVG itself, or linked if the SVG's is linked. This is easy to do by going to Extensions > Images > select either Embed Images or Extract Images.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I have to create the drawing application, not use it.

Comment: You cannot "link" an image inside a PDF.  Everything used by a given PDF (with a couple degrees of exception for unembedded fonts) has to be inside the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can program a java applet with Processing. It's cross-browser, can [export to pdf](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/pdf/index.html). Bitmap images would remain bitmap images embedded in the pdf.